# Can't get Twitter email when authenticating Twitter

Tags: python, twitter

I'm using Oauth1Session for authenticating Twitter and tried to get user's email info. Actually, the application have been successfully fetched user info but it's not included email info. How can I get email info with `accouunt/verify_credentials`.

My code:

```py
    access_token_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token'
    protected_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json'

    oauth_token = request.args.get('oauth_token')
    oauth_verifier = request.args.get('oauth_verifier')

    twitter = OAuth1Session(
        client_id,
        client_secret,
        oauth_token,
        oauth_verifier
    )

    response = twitter.post(
        access_token_url,
        params={'oauth_verifier': oauth_verifier}
    )
    access_token = dict(parse_qsl(response.content.decode("utf-8")))

    oauth = OAuth1Session(
        client_id,
        client_secret=client_secret,
        resource_owner_key=access_token["oauth_token"],
        resource_owner_secret=access_token["oauth_token_secret"]
    )

    params = {"include_email": True}

    response = oauth.get(protected_url, params = params)
    user_info = response.json()
```

**user_info**

> {'id': xxxxxxxxx, 'id_str': 'xxxxxxxx', 'name': 'xxxxxxxx', 'screen_name': 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'location': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'description': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'url': None, 'entities': {'description': {'urls': []}}, 'protected': False, 'followers_count': xxx, 'friends_count': xx, 'listed_count': xx, 'created_at': 'Thu Aug 27 14:16:29 +0000 2015', 'favourites_count': xxxx, 'utc_offset': None, 'time_zone': None, 'geo_enabled': True, 'verified': False, 'statuses_count': xxxxx, 'lang': None, 'status': {'created_at': 'Sun Dec 22 10:11:00 +0000 2019', 'id': xxxxxxxxxxx, 'id_str': 'xxxxxxxxxxx', 'text': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'truncated': False, 'entities': {'hashtags': [], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [], 'urls': []}, 'source': 'Twitter for iPhone', 'in_reply_to_status_id': None, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, 'in_reply_to_user_id': None, 'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None, 'in_reply_to_screen_name': None, 'geo': None, 'coordinates': None, 'place': None, 'contributors': None, 'is_quote_status': False, 'retweet_count': 0, 'favorite_count': 2, 'favorited': False, 'retweeted': False, 'lang': 'ja'}, 'contributors_enabled': False, 'is_translator': False, 'is_translation_enabled': False, 'profile_background_color': '000000', 'profile_background_image_url': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'profile_background_image_url_https': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'profile_background_tile': False, 'profile_image_url': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'profile_image_url_https': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'profile_banner_url': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'profile_link_color': 'DD2E44', 'profile_sidebar_border_color': '000000', 'profile_sidebar_fill_color': '000000', 'profile_text_color': '000000', 'profile_use_background_image': False, 'has_extended_profile': False, 'default_profile': False, 'default_profile_image': False, 'can_media_tag': False, 'followed_by': False, 'following': False, 'follow_request_sent': False, 'notifications': False, 'translator_type': 'none', 'suspended': False, 'needs_phone_verification': False}

But not included email...

Answer (score 1):

I have updated paramas:

```py
params = {"include_email": "true"}
```

Comment: Is this working now? I would have expected that change to help, if you already had the correct settings in the OAuth configuration.